# Row locking in case of DML

Tags: sql, oracle, locking, dml

I know that in case of DML statement row lock is acquired on the rows which are modified, but I am confused below of below statement from [this Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502):

> **A transaction that contains a DML statement does not require row locks
> on any rows selected by a subquery or an implicit query.**
>
> In the following sample UPDATE statement, the SELECT statement in
> parentheses is a subquery, > whereas the WHERE a > 5 clause is an
> implicit query:
>
> `UPDATE t SET x = ( SELECT y FROM t2 WHERE t2.z = t.z ) WHERE a > 5;`

My understanding is that lock will be acquired for all rows `WHERE a > 5` but this article seems to be saying contrary.

Could an Oracle expert please explain this.

Comment: It will not as stated in the documentation. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=de40e0bea3c7b66fa91e571df63013ed)

Comment: I think the intent of the docs is that it will not need locks on the table rows in the subquery, ie, table T2 in this case.

Comment: And as you've written: *row lock is acquired on the rows **which are modified***. Not all rows which conform `a > 5` are subject to update, and in addition to the Connor's comment they should not be locked also.

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald: document is clearly saying that no locking for `WHERE a > 5` as well.